# exclude words if the condition is satisfied

Tags: perl

I have this text file and I want to exclude the word "access" because a is followed by a, b or c at second, third or forth position.

```
# cat tt.txt
access
ample
taxing
```

I tried this, but it returns all 3 words.

```
# grep '[a-c][^a-c][^a-c][^a-c]' tt.txt
access
ample
taxing
```

---

Update 1:

I used over-simplified example above.

```
# cat tt.txt
access
bccess
ample
taxing
tacking
not

# grep -Ev '[a-c].{0,2}[a-c]' tt.txt
ample
taxing
not

# grep -E '[a-c].{0,2}[^a-c]' tt.txt
access
bccess
ample
taxing
tacking

# Expected
ample
taxing
```

Comment: You need to anchor your regex to start of string `^[a-c][^a-c]{3}`

Comment: I'm sure there's a dupe for this somehere...

Comment: @shantanuo: Please clarify why word `not` should not be in output as it is not a word that started with `[a-c]` with `[a-z]` from 2nd to 4th positions?

Comment: because there is no a, b or c in the word 'not'. May be I can do this using 2 grep statements. But that may or may not work on the actual text file.

Comment: A couple of questions.  (1) So you want: (a) Match words with `[a-c]` in them (b) But exclude those in which `[a-c]` on the 2/3/4 position follows `[a-c]` before it (which is why `tacking` is excluded but `taxing` isn't).  Is this correct? (2) The accepted answer seems to do as asked ... or does it not quite for some reason? Or do you simply want different solutions (and in which way)?

Comment: 1) Yes. That is correct. 2) Yes. The accepted answer is correct. But I am looking for a perl solution. With awk I will have to write a shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to exclude the word `access` because `a` is followed by `a`, `b` or `c` at second, third or forth position

It can be done using this `awk`:

```bash
awk '/[a-c]/ && !/[a-c].{0,2}[a-c]/' file

ample
taxing
```

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `[a-c]`: Match `a` or `b` or `c`
- `.{0,2}`: Match 0 to 2 of any characters
- `[a-c]`: Match `a` or `b` or `c`

---

Or else using look arounds in `gnu-grep`:

```bash
grep -P '^(?=.*[a-c])(?!.*[a-c].{0,2}[a-c])' file

ample
taxing
```

---

Same solution in `perl`:

```bash
perl -ne 'print if /[a-c]/ && !/[a-c].{0,2}[a-c]/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

As near as I can tell, your condition is:

1. String must contain one of `a`, `b` or `c`.
2. In pos 0-3, no abc may precede another abc.

Well then, why don't we just write the code like that.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    next unless /[a-c]/;                            # skip if no abc
    next if substr($_, 0, 4) =~ /(?<=[a-c])[a-c]/;  # skip if an abc is preceded by an abc 
    print;                                          # otherwise print
}

__DATA__
access
bccess
ample
taxing
tacking
not
```

This is a way to write code that emulates the diamond operator `<>`, used by `-n` and `-p` switches commonly used in Perl oneliners. We use the DATA file handle to emulate a file. If you wanted to swing this into a oneliner it would look something like

```
$ perl -ne' next unless /[a-c]/; next if substr($_, 0, 4) =~ /(?<=[a-c])[a-c]/; print; ' file.txt
```

I've tested it on your sample word list, and it seems to work as expected.